# Vqcache not working with a local Vagrant instance on Opencart

Tags: apache, permissions, opencart, vagrant, vqmod

So I have an existing opencart system with a vqmod extension on it. I'm trying to set this up locally to work on by can't get vqmod to create it's cache files. I'm using vagrant as the local environment.

I know vqmod has some crazy permissions requirements, I have it running on an external staging server but to get this to work I had to set the group to www-data all the way from server root right the way up to vqmod directory.

Am I missing something simple in vqmods permission requirements

Comment: You need to set **write permissions** to these folders: `<ROOT>/vqmod/vqcache/` and `<ROOT>/vqmod/log/` and to this file `<ROOT>/vqmod/mods.cache` (I believe it's called like this, do not remember). And, after copying the `vQmod` do not forget to install it by visiting this URL: `http://my.domain.com/vqmod/install/index.php`... The installation overwrites two files: `<ROOT>/index.php` and `<ROOT>/admin/index.php` so these have to be writeable, too...

Comment: Yeah I've done all of this.

drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant   408 Nov  8 15:26 vqmod/
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant     68 Nov  8 15:26 logs/
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant     68 Nov  8 15:25 vqcache/
-rwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant      0 Nov  8 15:25 mods.cache*

Think it may be more of a core system permissions issue but really cant put my finger on it

Comment: "crazy permissions" - Or just writable for the relevant folders. The permissions it says to set is because so many different servers use so many different setups for the hosting, that some require more relaxed permissions than others. Make sure you delete the mods.cache file and that your vqmod folder itself is writeable (since it needs to be to create the mods.cache file again)

Comment: mods.cache folder *claps* was the issue. As that file was created by a different server for whatever reason it didnt want to write to it, even with the same ownership and write permissions it has now. Deleting it and creating a new one sorted it. Wanna create that as an answer so I can tick it?